# Android SDK not found by PhoneGap/DreamWeaver CS6

Tags: android, cordova, dreamweaver

I'm trying to use PhoneGap on Dreamweaver CS6 with the Android SDK. Under Phonegap build settings, I add the location of the SDK('\Android\android-sdk').

I get back the following message "The SDK location provided for Android is not valid. Please verify your settings.".

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add two subdirectories to your path: /tools and /platform-tools

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: This works, to add the sub directories I had to run an update with the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the Android SDK and install it to a different directory.

Then point your Dreamweaver to that new directory.

You probably have to have a valid AVD there as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch the Android SDK Manager it shows you the SDK path at the top of that window. I just used that and it worked.